# Конвертировал программу python в файл с расширением .exe при запуске программа сразу закрывается

Tags: python, pyinstaller

```
import pyautogui as pa
import keyboard as kb

flag = False
f_start = False
print("Нажмите alt+n чтобы начать авторыбалку, alt+d чтобы остановить рыбалку,alt+d чтобы 
остановить программу")
while not flag:
    if f_start == True:
        pa.typewrite("/fish")
        pa.sleep(0.5)
        pa.press("enter")
        pa.sleep(1)
    if kb.is_pressed('alt+d'):
        f_start = False
        print("Рыбалка приостановлена")
    if kb.is_pressed('alt+n'):
        f_start = True
        print("Рыбалка начата")
    if kb.is_pressed('alt+q'):
        flag = True
```

Comment: А ошибка какая?

Comment: ошибок нет нужно чтобы программа не закрывалась

Comment: точно нет? что пишет в консоле?